# Does TVar in cats-stm require an immutable value?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

Ref in Cats-effect or Zio requires to work with immutable value over the mutable references, because of the underlying java compareAndSet from AtomicReference, I wonder if it is the case with TVar with cats-stm ?

Comment: I think the point is that you shouldn't share a reference to an object stored in TVar to other threads. The only way they should be able to access it is by the TVar interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TVar is still analogous to using a `var` in imperative code, so the type should be immutable